# What are the differences between Decision Trees and Subgroup Discovery Algorithms?

Tags: cart, algorithms

I'm reading a paper which states that subgroup discovery is:

> Subgroup discovery is a data mining technique whose goal is to detect interesting subgroups into a population with respect to a property of interest.

The paper goes on to make the distinctions between a decision tree and subgroup discovery, but does not explain the rationale/reasoning.

With a google search on subgroup discovery algorithms I find the following:

> The goal of the subgroup discovery algorithm SD, outlined in Figure 1, is to search for rules that maximize $q_{g} = \frac{TP}{FP + g}$, where TP are true positives, FP are false positives, and g is a generalization parameter. High quality rules cover many target class examples and a low number of non-target examples

and decision tree according to Wikipedia:

> A tree is built by splitting the source set, constituting the root node of the tree, into subsets which constitute the successor children. The splitting is based on a set of splitting rules based on classification features. This process is repeated on each derived subset in a recursive manner called recursive partitioning.

With this information and my prior knowledge of decision trees, I am not able to make a distinction between decision trees and subgroup discovery algorithms.

What are the differences between Decision Trees and Subgroup Discovery Algorithms?